# "await authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync" not running when called in Restful API

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, rest, async-await, dynamics-crm

Sorry for the poor title, but I'm not getting an error, it just isn't running.

I am trying to authenticate to our Dynamics 365 to get an Access Token so I can send data using the Dynamics API.

The following works fine when ran from a normal MVC Project site, however isn't working when called from the API.

Bellow is the full function:

```
public string TAF_SendDataToCRM(JObject AppJSON)
    {
        Task<String> IDTask = AuthenticateWithCRM(AppJSON);

        string ID = ApplicationIDTask.ToString();

        return ID;
    }

public async Task<String> AuthenticateWithCRM(JObject AppJSON)
        {
            ClientCredential clientcred = new ClientCredential(clientId, appKey);
            AuthenticationContext authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(aadInstance + tenantID);
            AuthenticationResult authenticationResult = await authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync(organizationUrl, clientcred);
            using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
            {
                httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(organizationUrl);
                httpClient.Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 2, 0);  // 2 minutes  
                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("OData-MaxVersion", "4.0");
                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("OData-Version", "4.0");
                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
                    new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization =
                    new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", authenticationResult.AccessToken);

                HttpResponseMessage CreateResponse = await SendAsJsonAsync(httpClient, HttpMethod.Post, "api/data/v8.2/crimson_whdapplications", AppJSON);

                Guid applicationID = new Guid();
                if (CreateResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    string applicationUri = CreateResponse.Headers.GetValues("OData-EntityId").FirstOrDefault();
                    if (applicationUri != null)
                        applicationID = Guid.Parse(applicationUri.Split('(', ')')[1]);
                    return applicationID.ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                    return null;
                }
            }
        }
```

Debugging will reach...

```
AuthenticationResult authenticationResult = await authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync(organizationUrl, clientcred);
```

At which point it will not reach the next line but will return to the function in which it was called and in IDTask will contain: `'Id = 38, Status = WaitingForActivation, Method = "{null}", Result = "{Not yet computed}"'` and when converted to string contain: 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[System.String]'

It doesn't error, it just reached the AuthenticationResult line and gives up.

Is this to do with the function being an `async` call and the AuthenticationResult using `await` which doesn't work within a Restful API call?

The full function may not be relevant, however if the Async/await is the issue when I'd like to know how else to do this Dynamics API call, as within the `using` another `await` is used for `HttpResponseMessage`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's

> return to the function

because of Task. You have to change this line:

```
 Task<String> IDTask = AuthenticateWithCRM(AppJSON);
```

to

```
var IDTask = await AuthenticateWithCRM(AppJSON);
```

You have to await your async operation, but for now you are trying to work with Task that still in progress.
Just add await and you will work with result of this "AuthenticateWithCRM(AppJSON)" operation.

"TAF_SendDataToCRM" should be async too. Every method in this tree should be async if you want to get any benefits from your Asyn calls.
Or just run this code in a sync way in your TAF_SendDataToCRM method.